# How do I fix "invalid group" error when attempting to use Gruber's "improved" URL matching regexp pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, gruber

I'm attempting to integrate John Gruber's [An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) into one of my Javascripts, but WebKit's inspector (in Google Chrome 5.0.375.125 for Mac) gives an "Invalid group" regular expression syntax error.

Gruber's original regexp is as follows:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

The line from my JavaScript w/the regexp is as follows (w/forward slashes backslash-escaped):

```
tweet_text = tweet_text.replace(/(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

And the Google Chrome (V8?) error is as follows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/: Invalid group
```

And the Safari error is as follows:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (?
```

He claims it should work in modern JavaScript regexp interpreters, which I'd assume WebKit & V8 would be. Does JavaScript's regexp syntax not support the `(?:` (damn Google for not indexing punctuation!) grouping syntax? Did I just miss escaping something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gah, it was the **mode modifier** (i.e. the `(?i)`) at the beginning of the regex!

I went through [Regular-Expressions.info's datails on "JavaScript's Regular Expression Flavor"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), specifically the list of what's *not* supported, and there was the 'mode modifier', which I had already specified after the closing forward slash of the regex. Ripped it out an all seems well.

So, my JavaScript regex is now as follows:

```
/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi
```

Comment: I'm actually having trouble matching 'example.com'. 'http://example.com' and 'www.example.com' both work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: By removing the \/ at the end of the third option for the domain name, I can make it work:

`\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4})(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))`

Comment: Ah, I see that Gruber was intentionally missing the example.com case, however, seems like a common one.

Comment: I agree that it's a common case and would be useful. That said, I understand Gruber's not wanting to match against specific TLDs for flexibility & forward compatibility and also not wanting it to match `filename.ext`.

Comment: After working on this over the day, I ended up with:
https://gist.github.com/920312